# Remove all but the text written by user

Tags: node.js, regex, outlook-restapi

I use `Outlook API` to fetch the sent email's body. Now, I want to clean the body to remove all links, headers, etc. and keep only the text written by user. Following is my regex function:

```
function getRegex() {

    var regex1 = /^(?=.*Forwarded message)[^]*/m;
    var regex2 = /^(?=.*From: )[^]*/m;
    var regex3 = /^(?=.*On )[^]*/m;
    var regex4 = /^(?=.*http)[^]*/m;

    return new RegExp("(" + regex1.source + ")|(" + regex2.source + ")|(" + regex3.source + ")|(" + regex4.source + ")");
}
```

Following is function to fetch sent emails from Outlook:

```
outlook.mail.getMessages({
    token: token.token.access_token,
    odataParams: queryParams,
    folderId: 'SentItems'

}, function (err, result) {

    if (err){
        console.log(err);
        return;
    }

    var mail_array = result.value;
    var outlook_sent_emails = '';

    mail_array.forEach(function (mail) {

        if (mail.BodyPreview !== '') {
            outlook_sent_emails += (mail.BodyPreview + " ");
        }
    });

    console.log(outlook_sent_emails.replace(getRegex(), ""));  //This is not working
});
```

This line `console.log(outlook_sent_emails.replace(getRegex(), ""));` shows I am still getting all links, headers, etc.

The same regex is working elsewhere in my code.

**EDITED:**

Sample Text:

```
  From: <Name>
    Sent: <Datetime>
    To: <Name>
    Subj Dear Sir/Madam


Hi Vaibhav,

Hope you are doing well.

http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

Sent from my Windows 10 phone
```

I want to remove all kinds of links and text like as follows from the string:

```
From: <Name>
Sent: <Datetime>
To: <Name>
Subj Dear Sir/Madam
```

**EXPECTED OUTPUT:**

```
 Hi Vaibhav,

 Hope you are doing well.
```

Comment: If you want to check if there is, say, `http` in *the entire* text, you need to also use `[^]*` in the lookahead, same as in the consuming pattern part. Try replacing all `.*` with `[^]*`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew doing that cleared all text and I got blank result.

Comment: Yes, because now your regex matched :) - and works as expected as `[^]*` is greedy and can match *any* character. Think about your requirements and post them. Right now, it is impossible to help you since we do not know what the contents look like.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew alright. I added my requirements.

Comment: try putting the "m" flag in second param `...(" + regex4.source + ")", 'm')` and remove it from the regex vars.

Comment: Could you please post a sample text and the expected output? Just a short example. Also, is `<Name>`, etc. the *whole line* or specific char sequence? What is the `regex4` supposed to match?

Comment: @ZiTAL that didn't work..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> UPDATE: added http

You may try this:

```
^.*(From:|Sent:|Sent\s+From|To:|Subj|Dear\s+(Sir|Madam)|http).*$
```

and replace by ""

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/tZRksF/6)

```js
const regex = /^.*(From:|Sent:|Sent\s+From|To:|Subj|Dear\s+(Sir|Madam)|http).*$/gmi;
const str = `  From: <Name>
    Sent: <Datetime>
    To: <Name>
    Subj Dear Sir/Madam


Hi Vaibhav,

Hope you are doing well.

http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

Sent from my Windows 10 phone`;
const subst = ``;
const result = str.replace(regex, subst).trim();
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Updated as per the latest sample i/o

Comment: @Vaibhav Agarwal, glad to know that it worked for you.. I think you know, what you want to replace, and also know the target mails for whom you want to apply that :)

Comment: Yeah..I understood this regex..I can make modifications as per my need. thanks a lot!